# Can I get is font italic/bold/light etc using library PhenX/php-font-lib?

Tags: php, fonts, dompdf, php-font-lib

So, I can get font name but also I need to know is font bold/italic/light etc. I try to investigate in code of this library but I have no success.

On [demo page](http://pxd.me/php-font-lib/www/font_explorer.html) of this library you can find a lot of information but no doc is present about it.

About italic I have idea that we can detect it by post->italicAngle (according to demo page). 
It should be non-zero value.

Is this correct?

Comment: don't just ask here, also file an issue on their github project issue tracker asking them for documentation. That way everyone gets a better future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the [`OS/2`](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/os2.htm) and [`name`](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/name.htm) tables ("Name IDs" section especially) for how all that information is organised. PHP-font-lib exposes the OpenType table data to you, so reading up on how to work with that data is your responsibility.